# How to query given grants on Oracle?

Tags: oracle

On a database I had to execute the following two statements:

```
GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO MyUSER;
GRANT DROP ANY TABLE TO MyUSER;
```

What I miss is the query which tells me that those grants are given. I don't see them in

```
select * from USER_TAB_PRIVS ORDER BY 2 ;
select * from USER_ROLE_PRIVS ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

`select * from user_sys_privs`

Comment: Correct. As "CREATE ANY TABLE" is not a table privilege (tied to a specific table) it's not listed in XXX_TAB_PRIVS.

Comment: I'll give you a hint for in the future @Vijay ... A longer answer is better. Maybe a tiny blurb about why they would do this?